# How to keep html text field value after pressing submit button

Tags: html, smarty

After filling the form fields , if there is any error , after I pressing on the Submit button , loosing the data that I already entered in the form fields.

How can I keep the form field values after pressing on the Submit button.

I have googled for Smarty solution , but did not get any thing yet . I want to get this solution in a Smarty form field.

Please see the code section here

Please help

Comment: Please share your code, as it's impossible for us to know what's happening. My guess though, is that you have a form with a 'submit' type button. A submit action clears the form upon submitting.

Comment: You could send the form to itself and simply output its value again. Don't think this is specific to smarty.

Comment: <input type="text" id="clientname" name="clientname" placeholder="Client Name" class="form-control" value="{$smarty.post.clientname}">

Comment: May this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641844/keep-file-input-value-after-validation-without-ajax/76641999#76641999