# Keep file input value after validation without ajax

Tags: php

I have a php form and I want to keep the file inputs value after validation and refreshing the page.
for example, I have a form with the following inputs:

- Name
- Mobile
- Profile Image

So the user set "profile image" and not set "name", but "name" is required and after the validation error I want to keep "profile image" data.

Comment: Validate via AJAX then. Don't refresh the page!

Comment: _"I want to keep the file inputs value after validation and refreshing the page"_ - You would need to repopulate the file-inputs, which you can't do. You can't decide which file should be selected in the clients file-input. If you could, it would be a _massive_ security issue. Is there any real reason you don't want/can't use the tool (Ajax) that essentially exists in order to solve these and similar kinds of problems?

Comment: If you want to do it without AJAX - then you can only show them the image that was already uploaded in the previous submission again, as an actual image; and then use that to populate the record when it finally gets stored, if they do not upload a _new_ one with that next request. You will need to keep track on where you stored the already uploaded image on the server then.

Comment: See the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute, it will work for the vast majority of the users.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by java script. You can define on-submit method on form and write down the custom validation rule. if validation is true the return that after that form is submit else form is contain data with file as it is.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function validateForm() {
                var name = document.getElementById("name");
                var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile");
                
                // Validation Rule Here
                if (name.value.trim() === "") {
                    alert("Name is required.");
                    return false;
                }
                //Write Other rule here
                return true; // return true if validation successfull
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
           <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
               <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name :"><br>
               <input type="tel" id="mobile" name="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile:"><br>
               <input type="file" id="File" name="File"><br>
               <input type="submit" value="Submit">
           </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```